# Unable to insert mail@id in oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, putty

I am unable to insert email id in the oracle 9i tables.
I am using putty.

`INSERT INTO email(mail_list)values('sundar@abc.com');`

I m getting the below error:
SQL> INSERT INTO email(mail_list)values('sundar@
abc.com');
`SP2-0042: unknown command "abc.com')" - rest of line ignored.`

Putty is not accepting `@` symbol.

I have read the below in one of the portal:

`The problem is common with unix environment with the display terminal keyboard settings. The sqlplus session had trouble interpreting the "@" sign, because it was assigned in the terminal to the "kill" setting.`

how to correct the issue?

Thanks

Sundar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert without having to use the @ character. Find out the ascii value:

```
SQL>select ascii('@') from dual;
64
```

And then compose the email addres using the CHR function.

```
INSERT INTO email(mail_list)values('sundar'||chr(64)||'abc.com');
```

(I have no knowledge of Putty so I used my SQL knowledge).

Answer (score -2):

Try with the below statement in SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(email) VALUES('xyz@gmail.com')
```